# File won't remove

Tags: java, file, delete-file, erase

I am trying to remove a file in java, but it will not remove. Could someone explain why it won't remove?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
File bellFile = new File("config\\normbells.txt");

bellFile.delete();

File bellFileNew = new File("config\\normbells.txt");

bellFileNew.createNewFile();

System.out.println("Done!");
```

NOTE: I am trying to wipe the file, if that helps.

Comment: What error message do you get, if any? Are you sure that the code is being run?

Comment: well, cuz you are creating the same darn file again :)

Comment: @chaitanya10 that is what it is supposed to do, it just doesn't wipe the file first.

Comment: @MarkByers the code is being run, because it outputs the messages that I have in it. No error messages.

Comment: @cheese5505: I'd guess you are looking in the wrong directory. It's a very common error - you're not the first to do it and you certainly won't be the last.

Comment: @MarkByers The file moves a lot, so I can't have a direct path.

Comment: are you trying to wipe the data from the file ,but not delete one ?

Answer (score 2):

File deletion can fail under the following circumstances:

1. The file does not exist.
2. The file is a directory not a file.
3. You don't have access to delete the file.
4. You don't have access to the the file or any of its parent directory.
5. The file is being used currently by some another application.

Try avoiding all the above mentioned circumstances & you'll surely able to delete the file.
Also before deleting the file add this condition :

```
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
}
```

Comment: The file does exist, the file is not a directory, it is in a directory where it can edit, that may be why, I will try, it is only used by my java program.

Comment: Also make sure it is not open while you're trying to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Java7 has new functionality for this.

```
Path target = Paths.get("D:\\Backup\\MyStuff.txt");
Files.delete(target);

Path newtarget = Paths.get("D:\\Backup\\MyStuff.txt");
Set<PosixFilePermission> perms
    = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rw-rw-rw-");
FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> attr
    = PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(perms);
Files.createFile(newtarget, attr);
```

Take a look at the File class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: I fixed the file in-use error, but now I get an error which says:

    `'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute`

Answer (score 0):

```
File bellFile = new File("config\\normbells.txt");
if(bellFile.delete())
{
System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

Comment: I want to re-create it though, so it wipes the file.

Comment: are you trying to wipe the data from the file ,but not delete one ?

Comment: Yes. I want to wipe the file.